# My command with reaction is not working can you help me? (bot discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I wanted to code a command on my bot. And I added reaction but I want that when the user who did the command, click on a certain reaction so it can display a different message. But what I did doesn't work so I please help me because I need this to be done.
Here is the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')


module.exports = {

 run: (message, reaction, user) => {

  message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("**COMBAT**")
  .setDescription("*Choisissez votre mode de combat*")
  .setColor('#CD5C5C')
  .addField("️", ' `est pour le mode de combat avec une arme non magique` ')
  .addField("", ' `est pour un mode de combat utilisant la magie` '))



},

name: "fight",
setDescription: "Cette commande sert à executer un combat"



}
```

and here is the command handler that I wrote down for the code :

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {

if (message.content === "~fight"){

    message.react'️'),
    message.react('')

    if (reaction.emoji.name === '️') {
        message.reply('nice')
    }
    else {
        message.reply('cool')
    }
}

 })
```

it's not showing me any error but it's not working

and this is my command handler

```
client.commands = new Discord.Collection()
console.log("Bot en ligne")

fs.readdir('./commands', (err, files) => {
if (err) throw err
 files.forEach(file => {
     if (!file.endsWith('.js')) return
     const command = require(`./commands/${file}`)
     client.commands.set(command.name, command)
 })
})
```

Comment: You didn't show the error, but I assume it's something like "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". This is because the `reaction` property is not what you think it is, and does not have the `emoji` property. Please show your command handler, or whichever function actually triggers this code.

Comment: "Please show your command handler, or whichever function actually triggers this code."

Comment: so I change things so you can see more clearly

Comment: `messageReactionAdd` does not pass a `message` parameter, `message.reaction.add()` is not a function, and that's still not the piece of code that triggers your command file.

Comment: ok I'm gonna change this but I don't understand what's the part that you want (I'm sorry I'm a beginner)

Comment: `message.content` will never equal `~fight` as `message` is actually corresponding to a `User` because `messageReactionAdd` doesn't pass a `Message` as a parameter, thus `message.content` is `undefined` because `Users` don't have the property `content`. Also, it seems like you have not written a way for the file to get triggered. I suggest reading the djs docs and guide.

Comment: `message.content === "~fight"` this looks odd, use indexOf

Comment: Thanks for adding in your command handler. Can you also show the `message` event where you actually *`run`* the functions? I believe the problem is the arguments you're passing being different from what you expect in the function.

Comment: so when I run the command ~fight it's working but it's not adding any reaction and when I add the reaction myself on the bot message it's telling me this :

xception has occurred: ReferenceError: message is not defined
  at Client.<anonymous> (e:\Discord bot\Index.js:48:5)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageReactionAdd.handle (e:\Discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageReactionAdd.js:46:17)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD] (e:\Discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD.js:4:37)

Comment: at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (e:\Discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (e:\Discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (e:\Discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (e:\Discord bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (e:\Discord bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)

Comment: john Smith, you mean like this?

if (indexOf ("~fight")){..}